# how to create new image with frame on it?

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, jquery-plugins

im going to create something like this http://www.photofacefun.com/photoframes/, its creating a new image with frame on it, can i do that with php, jquery, or html? or do i have to use any jquery library? is there any jquery plugin like this? doesnt matter if its a paid or free.

how can i add a frame to an image with php and jquery?

And on the example above, are they using php or another language? java maybe. I really have no idea about this.

thanks..

Comment: and why vote down if you cant answer?

Comment: Your Q is attracting downvotes, bc you are just asking for a solution and don't provide anything. We're here to help you, if you have problems with your code but can't do the work for you. If you have no idea of how to do this, using a module/plugin/snippet won't help you at all

Comment: Yeah you right. But how can i start do some code if i have no idea those programming language can do that or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [demo](http://alijafarian.com/demos/responsive-image-grids-using-css/) of a responsive image grid using only HTML and CSS.

You can find the [code](http://alijafarian.com/responsive-image-grids-using-css/) here as well.

You can remove the titles and paragraphs if you like and can make them behave as links using the http://www.something.com"> attribute.

On the example they are using jquery.

Comment: Iam sorry, but its not what i mean. I know how to make a frame with html and css, but its only show the frame on the browser, the image is still bothing change at all. I want to make the image file have a frame, so when i share it to facebook for example, the frame will still there along with the image.

Comment: Oh sorry then, I cannot help you

Comment: no its ok, i think i found the solution. I do with your way, and then convert the html to image, thats work.. :D
thanks for the answer anyway